# How do i compare an as3 string with a json array?

Tags: arrays, json, actionscript-3, flash

Im trying to compare two specific bits of information. One is in the form of a as3 string the other is in the form of a Json array.

The Json array shows customer data from a shop website. What i want to do is have as3 compare the string(i.e a customer name) with the data , and when it has found the matching name, only trace that customers specific information.

Im amusing id have to use a loop for the comparison , but im having trouble getting my head around how to convert the Json into specific junks that can then be compared individually with a string. Any help would be perfect.

Thanks

Comment: A sample of the JSON data would be extremely helpful.

Comment: hey sorry heres a sample of the data 
`


        "customers"    :   [        {
        "id":               "04aa1ab3-521b-11e3-a29a-bc305bf5da20",
        "name":             "fake name",
        "customer_code":    "00000002",
        "customer_group_id":         "6012cd22-5166-11e3-a29a-bc305bf5da20",
        "customer_group_name":       "All Customers",
        "first_name":             "test",
        "last_name":              "test",
        "company_name":           "",
        "email":                  "testest@yahoo.com",
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that JSON is just a standard AS3 object.  There's no magic going on here; loop through it as you would any other structure and run your comparisons as usual.

### Solution

```
var jsonObj:Object = {
    "customers": [
        {
            "id": "04aa1ab3-521b-11e3-a29a-bc305bf5da20",
            "name": "fake name",
            "customer_code": "00000002",
            "customer_group_id": "6012cd22-5166-11e3-a29a-bc305bf5da20",
            "customer_group_name": "All Customers",
            "first_name": "test",
            "last_name": "test",
            "company_name": "",
            "email": "testest@yahoo.com"
        }
    ]
}

var myString:String = "fake name";

for (var k:String in jsonObj.customers[0]) {
    var v:String = jsonObj.customers[0][k];

    if (v == myString) {
        trace(myString + "'s email is " + jsonObj.customers[0].email)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Dictionary Object to store customer objects using their unique names (or ids ) as reference;
You certainly do not want to write unnecessary loop search for a customer in question.

**Solution**.

```
 var jsonObj:Object = {
"customers": [
    {
        "id": "04aa1ab3-521b-11e3-a29a-bc305bf5da20",
        "name": "fake name",
        "customer_code": "00000002",
        "customer_group_id": "6012cd22-5166-11e3-a29a-bc305bf5da20",
        "customer_group_name": "All Customers",
        "first_name": "test",
        "last_name": "test",
        "company_name": "",
        "email": "testest@yahoo.com"
    }
 ]
  }


 //Dictionary  Object to store customers
  var customers:Dictionary=new Dictionary();

//customer object in the json
  var customer:Object;

//loop json object to retrieve customers and  
//store them in Dictionary using either unique name or id
 for each(customer in jsonObj)
      customers[customer.name]=customer;


  //retrieve customer in question
  function getCustomer(id:String):Object
  {
        return customers[id] as Object; 
  }
```